# I'm trying to randomize 5 selections from a list of people

Tags: discord.js

This might be less difficult than I'm making it out to be, but I'm trying to make a Discord.JS bot command, that will take however many arguments I have. For example: !randomize 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
And the bot would respond with something like: "I have chosen: 4,2,7,3,9!" Any help?

Current attempt: Not exactly sure what I'm doing.

````
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}`

`bot.on('message', async msg => {
    if(msg.content === "!add") {
        //message.member.user.tag
        var msgArray = msg.content.split(" ");
        var args = msgArray.slice(1);
        var user = args[1];
        //if(!args[1]) return msg.channel.send("Please specify an argument!");
        if(nameList.includes(user)) {
            msg.reply("You're already on the list.")
        } else {
            nameList.push(args[1]);
            msg.channel.send(`${args[1]} has been added to the list!\n Current List:` + nameList);
        }
    }

    if(msg.content === "!bonus") {
        if(nameList.length === 0) {
            msg.reply("Either the list is empty, or I'm not in the mood!");
        } else {
            shuffleArray(nameList);
            var chosenOne = nameList.pop();
            nameList = [];
            msg.reply(chosenOne + ' has been chosen! Good luck!');
        }
    }

    if(msg.content === "!list") {
        if(nameList.length === 0) {
            msg.channel.send("Either the list is empty, or I'm not in the mood!");
        } else {
            msg.channel.send('The current list:' + nameList);
        }
    });```
````

Comment: Please share your current attempt so that we can show how to improve it and solve the problem.

Comment: Edited and added.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some simple steps to select 5 random elements from an array...

1. Construct an array of possible selections. In this example I've used names for the first 10 letters of the alphabet. In your code, it'll be the command arguments or predefined `nameList`.
2. Make a new array to hold the elements picked.

   *At some point before #3, you should check to make sure the pool the user has provided is large enough to make 5 selections ([`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)).*
3. Use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to execute the next code multiple times.
4. Generate a random number representing the index of a selected element ([`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)/double NOT bitwise operator).
5. [Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Description) the selection into the array.
6. Remove the chosen element from the original pool ([`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)).
7. Return the results.

```js
const pool = ['Albert', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Edward', 'Francis', 'George', 'Horacio', 'Ivan', 'Jim'];

const selected = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const num = ~~(Math.random() * pool.length);

  selected.push(pool[num]);
  pool.splice(num, 1);
}

console.log(`I have chosen: ${selected.join(', ')}`);
```

Take this example and manipulate it within your code to suit your purpose.